# C++ Copying an array of chars using char* (no string libraries)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, char

I am writing a C++ function that is supposed to duplicate an array of chars by copying each element character-by-character into a new array. Ideally, if I make the statements

```
char* a = "test";
char* b = copyString(a);
```

then both a and b should contain the string "test." However, when I print the copied array b, I get "test" plus a series of nonsense characters that seem to be the pointer. I don't want those, but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

My current function is as follows:

```
char* copyString(char* s)
{
     //Find the length of the array.
    int n = stringLength(s);

    //The stringLength function simply calculates the length of 
    //the char* array parameter.

    //For each character that is not '\0', copy it into a new array.
    char* duplicate = new char[n];

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        duplicate[j] = s[j];

        //Optional print statement for debugging.
         cout << duplicate[j] << endl;
    }

    //Return the new array.
    return duplicate;
}
```

For the purposes of understanding certain aspects of C++, I cannot use string libraries, which is where other answers I have found have fallen short in this case. Any help with this problem is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I though my stringLength function was fine - perhaps I was wrong.

```
int stringLength(char* s)
{
    int n;

    //Loop through each character in the array until the '\0' symbol is found. Calculate the length of the array.
    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        n = i + 1;
    }

    //Optional print statement for debugging.
    // cout << "The length of string " << s << " is " << n << " characters." << endl;

    return n;
}
```

Comment: I suspect your `stringLength` function doesn't count the null terminator.

Comment: Obvious case of "no 0 terminator"...

Comment: Perhaps I should have included it in my question. (EDIT: pressing Enter seems to post the comment instead of skipping a line.)

Comment: what about `int stringLength(const char* s) { int n = 0; for (; *s; s++, n++); return n; }`, saves a variable and avoids index operator. `-O3` optimizes both functions to about the same assembly so maybe doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 6):

You need to copy the 0 too. That's what a C-style string is, a null-terminated character array.

Really, all you need to do is add one to the length:

```
    int n = stringLength(s) + 1; // include the '\0'
```

And then everything else will account for itself - you'll allocate an array of sufficient size, and copy the `'\0'` in your loop too.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I made the changes you suggested and my function works fine now. I'll be sure to keep that null-termination concept in mind when dealing with C-strings in the future.